# undefined error for array.length AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm converting xml to html Table, but in inner for-loop i'am getting `undefined` error for `Row[i].cell.length` inspite of having `SPACER` in that cell

Find demo  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w893r5m9/)

Needed output table - [image: Table]

NOTE: alert you will be getting is the `length` of that row

Comment: For a starter when you debug JS you should use `console.log` instead of alert as alert is very limited and it stops JS execution which may lead to false positive scenarios

Comment: @maurycy okay but any idea why its saying `undefined` when there is a object there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised when the **Row** node has **one single element** inside.

I have modified the code for transform the string element into array, but after correcting the error have come out others I've tried to correct, but I think they should be reviewed.

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w893r5m9/2/)

Here the new code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.allText = '<Table rowSize="22"><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpan="true">Cat. No. </Cell><Cell cellWidth="2795" realIndex="1">Suitable Copper Conductor Range </Cell><Cell cellWidth="3150" realIndex="2">Limiter Fuse </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpan="true">SCCR, A </Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1">Line </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1">Load </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">Ampere Max </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">Fuse Class </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="3"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpan="true">DK35H </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpan="true" columnSplitIndex="1">1/0 - 12 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpan="true" columnSplitIndex="1">1/0 - 12 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">225 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">J </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpan="true">100,000 </Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">225 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">T </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">100 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">RK1 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">30 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">RK5 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">60 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">G </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">30 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">CC </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="1"><Cell cellWidth="9245" realIndex="0" colSpanSize="4"> SPACER </Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpan="true">DKK4-TF (5X20) UPPER </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpan="true" columnSplitIndex="1">10 - 18 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpan="true" columnSplitIndex="1">10 18 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">60 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">J </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpan="true">100,000 </Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">60 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">T </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">30 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">RK1 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">- </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">RK5 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">50 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">G </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">30 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">CC </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="1"><Cell cellWidth="9245" realIndex="0" colSpanSize="4"> SPACER </Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpan="true">DKK4-TF (5X20) LOWER </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpan="true" columnSplitIndex="1">10 18 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpan="true" columnSplitIndex="1">10 18 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">60 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">J </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpan="true">100,000 </Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">60 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">T </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">30 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">RK1 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">- </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">RK5 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">50 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">G </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row><Row cellSize="4"><Cell cellWidth="1500" realIndex="0" rowSpanIndex="0"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1470" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="1" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1325" realIndex="1" rowSpanIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="1"></Cell><Cell cellWidth="1530" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">30 </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1620" realIndex="2" columnSplitIndex="2">CC </Cell><Cell cellWidth="1800" realIndex="3" rowSpanIndex="5"></Cell></Row></Table>';
  $scope.processData = function(allText) {
    var xmlText = allText.replace(/\n/, '')
    var x2js = new X2JS();
    var json = x2js.xml_str2json(xmlText);
    var str = JSON.stringify(json);
    $scope.json = str;
    $scope.data = json.Table.Row;

    for (var i = 0; i < json.Table.Row.length; i++) {
      //var cells = json.Table.Row[i].Cell.length;
      var header = 0;

      // Transform the object into array
      if (json.Table.Row[i].Cell.constructor !== Array) {
         var asArray = [];
         asArray.push(json.Table.Row[i].Cell);
         json.Table.Row[i].Cell = asArray;
      }

      //alert( json.Table.Row[i].Cell.length)
      for (var j = 0; j < json.Table.Row[i].Cell.length; j++) {
       //alert(json.Table.Row[i].Cell[j].__text);
        //Row Span initialization
        if (json.Table.Row[i].Cell[j]._rowSpan) {
          json.Table.Row[i].Cell[j]['rSpan'] = '1';
        }

        //Column Span
        if (json.Table.Row[i].Cell[j]._colSpanSize != null) {
          var limit = json.Table.Row[i].Cell[j]._colSpanSize;
          var count = 0;
          while (limit > 0) {
            if (json.Table.Row[0].Cell[header].cSpan != null) {
              count += json.Table.Row[0].Cell[header].cSpan;
            } else {
              count++;
            }
            header++;
            limit--;
          }
          json.Table.Row[i].Cell[j]['cSpan'] = count;
        }

        //Row Span
        if (json.Table.Row[i].Cell[j]._rowSpanIndex != null) {
          var col = json.Table.Row[i].Cell[j]._rowSpanIndex;
          var row = i;
          while (!json.Table.Row[row].Cell[col]._rowSpan) {
            row--;
          }
          json.Table.Row[row].Cell[col].rSpan++;
        }

        //Column Split
        if (json.Table.Row[i].Cell[j]._columnSplitIndex != null) {
          var count = 1,
            col = j,
            k = 0;
          var index = json.Table.Row[i].Cell[j]._columnSplitIndex;
          if (json.Table.Row[i - 1].Cell[k] == null) {
            continue;
          }

          // here check for undefined
          while (
          json.Table.Row[i - 1].Cell[k] &&
                json.Table.Row[i - 1].Cell[k]._realIndex != index) {

                k++;
          }

          // here check for undefined
          if (json.Table.Row[i - 1].Cell[k] &&
              json.Table.Row[i - 1].Cell[k]._columnSplitIndex != null) {
            continue;
          }
          if (json.Table.Row[0].Cell[index].cSpan != null) {
            continue;
          }
          while (json.Table.Row[i].Cell[col]._columnSplitIndex == json.Table.Row[i].Cell[col + 1]._columnSplitIndex) {
            count++;
            col++;
          }
          json.Table.Row[i - 1].Cell[k]['cSpan'] = count;
        }
      }
    }
    $scope.data = json.Table.Row;
    if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
  }
});
```